# edit multi-level json in javascript, similary like Ruby translations can read them (from array/string)

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

Heres what i want achieve. I have multi-level json, like so:

```
 var json = {
   'first_level': {
     'second_level': ['one', 'two']
   },
   'another_first_level': true
 }
```

and i want to read/edit it like so:

```
load('first_level.second_level');
save('first_level.second_level', ['one', 'two', 'lol']);
```

Reading is simple:

```
 function load(path) {
   var arr = path.split('.');
   var result = json;

   arr.forEach(function(v, i){
     result = result[arr[i]];
   });

   return result;
 }
```

but i have no idea, how to actually update json variable, from the same string format.. And it might be even 10 levels deep..

Is it possible?

Heres a codepen with current example: http://codepen.io/ExClouds/pen/jWBrob?editors=001

Comment: It's just like reading, but you stop on the last element of the path and assign to that.

Comment: Not working, cos i will end up json containing only the last level.. i tried, but it didnt work out..

Comment: You haven't posted that code, so it's hard to say what's wrong. That's definitely how the process should work however.

Comment: ups, didn't login.. updated url

Comment: You said you tried the `save()` code - where is that?

Comment: I have it in the codepen.. but i cant figure out how to update the correct level, without losing all of the json.... that's why i'm posting this question here..

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i figured out how to do this.

Heres the answer:

```
 function save(path, value) {
   var fun = 'json.' + path + '=' + JSON.stringify(value)
   eval(fun);
 }
```

i also updated codepen, for anyone who might like this: http://codepen.io/ExClouds/pen/jWBrob?editors=001